# How to show number in sorted order after submit from input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to type few numbers in input(e.g=>12, 45, 2, 23, 65..) and when I click "Proceed Button", this should list down in sorted order.

This is how I tried but not working as expected...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState([]);
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [sortedList, setSortedList] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setInputData(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    setList([...list, inputData])
    for(let i =0; i<list.length; i++){
      if([list[i]< list[i+1]]){
        let temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
        list[i + 1] = temp;    
      }
      return list
    }
    // console.log(sortedList)
    setSortedList(list)
    setInputData('')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={inputData}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>Proceed</button>
      </div>
      <div>{sortedList?.map((item, index)=>{
        return(
          <h4 key={index}>{item}</h4>
        )
      })}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried showing list after my Proceed button which was showing list until I wrote the sorting logic which is giving me null value

Comment: First of all you're using `index` as key in an array that you are changing order of elements in which will always lead to headaches. You're also mutating state in your 'sort'

Comment: @pilchard what would be the best approach then?

Comment: The updated `list` state won't be available until the next render cycle, so either use the manually updated value in the `setSortedList()` call [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sort-as-side-effect-ms24n5?file=/src/App.js), or use a `useEffect` dependent on `list` to update the sortedList [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-to-update-sorted-list-1cmy7k?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It is generally recommended to handle side-effects yourself in the handler as in the first option [React: You might not need an effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect). Though in this case you probably don't even need two states since the sorted state is just a copy of the data meaning you could just sort directly before your map `{list && [...list].sort().map(...` [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/derivative-state-0bqgln?file=/src/App.js)